# trying to stripe two EBS volumes using user data from the launch configuration in cloud formation template

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

- created two EBS volumes using cloud formation template.
- attached EBS volumes using aws ec2 attach volume
- trying to stripe two volumes using - mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=0 --name=InfluxRaid --raid-devices=2 /dev/xvdb /dev/xvdc\n
  and i am getting error /dev/xvdb is not found.

Comment: You have a mismatch between the device names that you are specifying and the actual ones.

To help solve this complete the following steps:

In the AWS EC2 console, what devices names is AWS assigning for these volumes?

Inside the EC2 instance what are the device names?

Comment: device names are correct, i am thinking when mdadm is looking for devices they are still in the attaching state or not yet attached because mdadm works when i attach the volumes using block device mapping in the cloud formation template

Comment: @Nani I really wouldn't be too sure of that.  Some instance types call them strange names, like (iirc) xvdca, xvdcb, etc.  The volumes should attached by the time the script runs.

Comment: when i am attaching the volumes using device mappings i am able to stripe the volumes with same names but when i am attaching volumes from user script i am not able to stripe them

Answer (score 1):

While it's hard to say without more details, I suspect it's related to a delay in attaching the volumes to your instance during startup. See this [forum post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=89073) for more details, but I think you might want to add some wait in your `UserData` script, like:

```
# Wait for the EBS volume to show up
while [ ! -e /dev/sdh ]; do echo Waiting for EBS volume to attach; sleep 5; done
```